# TeamCity: how to copy zip file as artifact with a different name (instead of including it)

Tags: teamcity

My build creates a zip file, which I would like to designate as the build artifact with one exception: I would like to use the build number in the name of the zip file.

Something like:

`foo/bar.zip => foo_v%build.number%.zip`

Unfortunately, what I end up with is a bar.zip inside of b

Comment: when creating `bar.zip` why not use the build.number from the start? then you can add it as a 'regular' artifact.

Comment: bar.zip is created by MSBuild, is %build.number% exposable to MSBuild?

Comment: yes. in your batch file instead of using `set zipname = bar.zip` you can use something like `set zipname = foo_%build.number%.zip`. If TeamCity is doing your build then you can reference this from within MSBuild using `$(BUILD_NUMBER)`

Comment: @wal that does work, but in addition to that, I had to extend the AfterBuild target to clean up the zip file, and set MSBuild targets in TeamCity to `Clean;Build` in order to make sure I don't keep accumulating zip files. If you want to write up your advice as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: ok. you could do a del *.zip in the pre-build script as well (if you didnt want to clean) however I think cleaning is a good idea anyway on a CI server. (certainly doesnt hurt). have added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment:

in your batch file instead of using

```
set zipname = bar.zip
```

you can use something like

```
set zipname = foo_%build.number%.zip.
```

If TeamCity is doing your build then you can reference this from within MSBuild using `$(BUILD_NUMBER)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the good workaround could be to let TeamCity zip files for you

Comment: The zip composition is non-trivial, so while I could work around it by rerouting from the zip to a folder structure and then let TeamCity zip things up for me, it's not ideal. That may be my best bet, but I was hoping to find a simpler solution.